# Checking multiple values returned from an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query on a table which returns two values (call it fstValue and lstValue). I am trying to get my query to return True in cases when the fstValue >=0 AND lstValue <=100, and false in all other cases.

Is there any way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when fstValue >=0 AND lstValue <= 100
            then 'true'
            else 'false'
       end as result
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This one:

```
set @firstvalue = 98;
set @lastvalue = 100;
select case when (@firstvalue>=0 and @firstvalue<=100) 
and @lastvalue>=0 and @lastvalue<=100 then  'True'
 else  'False' end as '0 to 100';
```

Comment: This one if firstvalue and secondvalue is between 0 to 100 returns true else returns false;